# python + why diff between python command line to Visual studio

Tags: python

I am very new in python

To know Object and Class I start with this program

I write it on Python 3.3.2 Console (command Line )
and in the end I get the expected values - 28000 as expected

```
>>> class person:
            def personSalary(self,salary):
                            self.salary=salary
            def printSalary(self):
                            print (self.salary)


>>> obj=person()
>>> obj.personSalary(28000)
>>> obj.salary
28000
>>>
```

But when I write the code on Visual studio2010 ( python is plug-in in VS)

And run it without errors, then I don’t get any output ( value 28000 isn’t displayed )

```
class person:
   def personSalary(self,salary):
        self.salary=salary
   def printSalary(self):
        print (self.salary)

obj=person()
obj.personSalary(28000)
obj.salary
```

why? , on the Python console the code return the salary value and on Visual Studio it isn’t?

Comment: In the Python console, the output of the last command is always printed to stdout. By contrast, when you run a script (which is what I expect VS 2010 is doing), the output is only printed if you explicitly use `print` or similar.

Comment: that's how REPL works, or print it manually.

Comment: if you want , you can answer your solution and I will vote,